# How to increase height of first row image in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I want to design like this in bootstrap css , [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uAfZ.png)

What i have tried is

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-3">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="img1.jpg">             
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="img3.jpg">             
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="img5.jpg">             
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="img2.jpg">             
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="img4.jpg">             
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="img6.jpg">             
</div>

</div>
```

The height of images `img1.jpg,img4.jpg,img5.jpg` need to increase as shown in image attcahed,

Is there any Experts in  CSS?

Comment: I am no expert, but you can set min-height or max-height where you want it.

Comment: can you show example jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Add the `.img-fluid` class to each of your images so they scale with the parent `div`'s. That should work.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/#responsive-images

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired layout with modification on your html code. Try this code.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img1.jpg"> 
        <br>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img2.jpg">            
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img3.jpg"> 
        <br>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img4.jpg">            
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img5.jpg">
        <br>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img6.jpg">             
    </div>
</div>
```